# Can I re-use a pointer in this case?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

Suppose:

```
struct Foo
{
    Obj* pObj;
    Foo() : pObj(NULL);
};

Obj* CreateObj()
{
   //do some stuff and then
   return new Obj; //obj is a class
}

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.pObj = CreateObj();
   DoSomeOperationWithTheObj( foo.pObj );
   //suppose foo is a monster that should be 'killed' or deleted now
   delete foo.pObj;
   foo.pObj = NULL;
   //the question is can this pointer be 're-used' now like this:
   foo.pObj = CreateObj(); //create another object
}
```

Since the pointer was deleted, isn't there a problem re-using it right?

Comment: Don't confuse a pointer with the object which it "points" to.

Comment: @pst what you mean is that I should do `delete *foo.pOBj`?

Comment: Yes, you can reassign the pointer to a new/different object

Comment: A pointer is just like any other variable, if you don't use it for anything else anymore you can reuse it for whatever purpose floats your boat. You wouldn't ask if it was a normal `int` variable would you? ;)

Comment: @ViniyoShouta No, you shouldn't (in response to your response to *pst*'s comment).

Comment: Related question (same question, but for C) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504948/is-it-safe-to-reuse-pointers-variables-after-freeing-what-they-point-to

Comment: @ChristianRau, what about Fred's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2449530/1513286

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Well, he speaks about a totally different case, when using a pointer to a pointer. If this was a joke (as *Fred*'s answer also was a bit), then Ok (but from your question and comment I guess it wasn't), but otherwise don't refer to answers to random questions or at least read the respective question and answers thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your original question: yes, you can reassign to pointers like that. A pointer holds just a memory address and nothing more.

But you should not actually ever do this because handling raw pointers like this can lead to bugs, you already have a few of those in your code. Modern C++ allows you to do this way more nice and without concern. Suppose we start from this (compilable) code, i replaced Obj by an int, but the fact that it's a native type instead of a class does not matter:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int* pObj;
    Foo() : pObj(NULL) {}
};

int* CreateObj()
{
   return new int(42); //obj is a class
}

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.pObj = CreateObj();
   std::cout << *foo.pObj << std::endl;
   delete foo.pObj;
   foo.pObj = new int(13);
   std::cout << *foo.pObj << std::endl;
   delete foo.pObj;
}
```

We can convert this to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> pObj;
    Foo() : pObj(NULL) {}
};

std::unique_ptr<int> CreateObj()
{
   return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42));
}

int main()
{
   Foo foo;
   foo.pObj = CreateObj();
   std::cout << *foo.pObj << std::endl;
   foo.pObj = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(13));
   std::cout << *foo.pObj << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the major change is that I removed raw pointers and replaced them with the [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) wrapper. This has a few advantages:

1. You clearly state ownership, a `unique_ptr` can only be owned by the current scope. While createObj creates the object, by returning the temporary (nameless) `unique_ptr` it releases ownership so the caller can delete it whenever it wants. This will avoid tricky memleaks.
2. Deletes happen automatically for you, either when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope or when it is overridden (e.g. by the assignment operator).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can re-use the pointer. A pointer is just a way to refer to an object. Since you delete the object, you are free to use the pointer for whatever you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no problem in doing that. Pointers are just containers of addresses (analogous to variables which contains values).

`new` allocates an object and returns an address to it. You can then just assign the result address to any pointer (of the proper type) you want, whether it may be `delete`d pointers,  pointers holding "existing" allocated objects, NULL-holding pointers or uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to reuse a pointer, as long as the memory previously allocated is deallocated first, as you already did in your code.

When you `delete` a pointer, you actually free the memory it points to. The value of the pointer(*the starting address of that memory*) is unchanged, until you reassign it by `pointer = NULL` or `pointer = new ..`

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the pointer because you never deleted the pointer; you deleted the `Obj` that the pointer was pointing to. Keep in mind that a pointer is storing a memory address. So, just like you can change an int to a different value, you can always change a pointer to remember, or point, to a different memory address. Also, when you perform the delete operation on `foo.pObj`, you are not saying "delete foo.pObj". Instead you are saying "delete the Obj that foo.pObj is pointing to".

Where a problem would arise is if you tried to do something to the object that `foo.pObj` is pointing to after you performed the `delete` operation.